# Constant vs increasing acceleration for reference frames

Tags: acceleration

I was reading [this](http://staff.washington.edu/aganse/blog/files/centrip.html#thank) webpage created by a professional physicist and was shocked regarding his statement on constant acceleration not being sufficient for producing the old "ball flies into the backseat" phenomenon.  Am I reading it incorrectly or is there something very wrong here? (skip to second asterisk)

Comment: He's just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As John Davis wrote, he's just wrong.

The right response to Fernando's statement in that cited page, *The accelerating force exerted on the ball by the moving vehicle makes the ball fall back down to the same spot it was thrown from,* is "What accelerating force? There is none."

To make it more obvious that there is none, let's put the person in a spaceship accelerating at 1 *g*. That person will feel exactly the same forces as a person standing still on the surface of the Earth. When a person on the surface of the Earth lets a ball drop, the ball of course falls. Exactly the same thing will happen on that spaceship. The connection between the spaceship's acceleration and the ball's acceleration vanishes the instant the person let's the ball loose.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was losing it. I'm still shocked. I'm not trying to be a tattletale but isn't that like ninth grade physics? Both of these guys are professional physicists.

Comment: @Brian - Here's another way to look at it: You found a random page on the internet. Is every random page you read on the internet true? Contrary to popular opinion, this is not the case. One difference between this site and random pages you find on the 'net: At this site, people would jump all over me (and rightfully so!) if my answer to your question was wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by the page being "random". Check the url and his CV.

Answer (score 0):

It means that when a car starts accelaration and is constantly accelarating. Then if the ball is released first or a littel time after the car starts, in both the cases the ball would seem to fly backward. This is becouse when the ball is thrown upward it had the velocity that had the car at that moment and moves at that velocity untill it returns(if there is no air resistance)while the car is continiously accelarating that means that when the ball was thrown upward, it had the same velocity on release and return becouse after that no force act on the ball, while the car would have gained greater velocity as compared to the ball and hence the ball would fall backward.
I may say that the Physicist did not say what you mean.